# Simple hash table for a conversion R script

Tags: r, hash, hashtable

I would like to use hash table to implement simple coversion script.
An input should be multiplied with a factor using its symbol, i.e. y = x * 1E-12, should be called e.g. `y <- X2Y(x,"p")` with "p" being the symbol for 1E-12.

```
library(hash)

sym2num <- function(x) {
  h <- hash( c("f"=1E-15,"p"=1E-12,"n"=1E-9,"mu"=1E-6,"m"=1E-3,"c"=1E-2) )
  return(h$x)
}

X2Y <- function(X,x) {
  xNum <- sym2num(x)
  Y <- X * xNum
  return(Y)
}

# y = x * 1E-12
y <- X2Y(x,"p")
print(y)
```

With the above code I get *numeric(0)* as result. Any idaes where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no benefit to using the {hash} library here. Indeed, since you rehash your vector before each subsetting, this will be *substantially less efficient* than a direct lookup.

Even if you only constructed the hash table once instead of repeatedly, it would probably *still* be faster not to use it: the hash table implementation carries a substantial constant overhead. It’s only faster than direct vector or list subsetting for fairly large tables.

Instead, just do this:

```r
sym2num <- function(x) {
  c(f = 1E-15, p = 1E-12, n = 1E-9, mu = 1E-6, m = 1E-3, c = 1E-2)[x]
}
```

This is idiomatic, efficient R code.

---

Fundamentally, the mistake in your R code was the subsetting, `h$x`. This fails because the subset operator `$` doesn’t work with variables, it expects an *unevaluated name* on its right-hand side. The code will thus always look up the literal name `x` inside `h`. thc’s answer shows how to avoid the issue.

Comment: The small table size could've just been for the sake of example.  It doesn't take a much longer table for hash to be more efficient than R vector.

Comment: There is an issue with your version of sym2num, e.g. `sym2num("p")` gives the two outputs, `p` and `1e-12`, while I need only the number. How to get rid of the `p`?

Comment: @ohemjeh No, it only gives a single output. That output has a name but that isn’t an issue. If you want to get rid of the name for aesthetic reasons, you can call `unname` on it.

Comment: Yes, that works. Btw, because I forgot to mention, your answer was very insightful, thanks for for taking the time to write it!

Answer (score 1):

Your function `sym2num` always returns the hash of "x", which is NULL.

`h$x` is a shortcut for `h[["x"]]`, but what you want is `h[[x]]`.

Instead use this:

```
sym2num <- function(x) {
  h <- hash( c("f"=1E-15,"p"=1E-12,"n"=1E-9,"mu"=1E-6,"m"=1E-3,"c"=1E-2) )
  return(h[[x]])
}
```